# how to initialize a vector member variable of reference_wrapper inside a class?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, reference-wrapper

How to initialize a vector of reference_wrapper member variable in a class.
I have tried to initialize with a vector in constructor initialisation_list.

```
 class Test
    {
    public:
        Test(std::vector<int> vec) :vec_r(begin(vec), end(vec)) // not working
        {
        }
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vec_r; //member variable
    };

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,3 };
        Test testObj(v);
        
        std::cout << testObj.vec_r[0].get() <<'\n'; // prints unintialised value 
        std::cout << testObj.vec_r[1].get() <<'\n'; // prints unintialised value 
        std::cout << testObj.vec_r[2].get() <<'\n'; // prints unintialised value 
        return 0;
    }
```

Is there any other way to initialize a 'reference_wrapper' vector in a class?

Comment: Why not just store a reference to the entire vector?  A `const vector<int>&` member would give you access to all of the elements but stop you from being able to modify the vector itself.

Comment: The argument variable `vec` is passed *by value*. The vector and all data in it will cease to exist once the constructor returns. Saving references to data in the vector is pointless and wrong.

Comment: On another and unrelated note, why do you use `printf` for your printing? Why not e.g. `std::cout << testObj.vec_r[0] << '\n';`?

Comment: So you don't actually need a vector of reference wrappers?  The code you have currently should work, it's just that `vec` wasn't passed by reference so `vec_r` is storing references to objects that no longer exist.

Comment: @NathanOliver, if I change 'vec' as reference_wrapper vector, then this code works.

Also, if 'vec_r' is not a member variable, std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vec_r(begin(vec), end(vec)); works.

Comment: I think that @NathanOliver meant that you should make both the `vec` argument *and* the `vec_r` member variables references. So that `vec_r` reference the original vector `v` from the `main` function. I.e. `Test(std::vector<int> const& vec) : vec_r(vec) {}` and then `std::vector<int> const& vec_r;` This will also remove the unnecessary copy of `v` to the argument variable `vec`.